# First Derivative Test Not Finding All Critical Points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

f(x) = $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + x + 2}$

I set it to 0 to find the critical points, so I get $x^2 = 0$ and $x = 0$ is a min. However, there also exists a maximum at $-4$. Why doesn't the first derivative test show this?

[EDIT]:

Hi everybody, I am Ssso Ssorry: I meant f(x) to be f'(x). See the question in the textbook was 'on what interval is the curve

y = definite integral from 0 -> x [t^2/(t^2 + t + 2)dt.

So when I took the first derivative, I just replaced the t's with x's (as above). So when I set (what I termed f(x) above) the first derivative to = 0, I just got x^2 = 0, i.e., x = 0.

So what I'm asking is, why didn't I get all the critical points from the first derivative of the integral?

Note: Intuitively I understand that I just replaced the functions t's with x's i.e., the function wasn't technically differentiated...Is it because y' returned f(x) instead of a first differentiation?

Thanks to everybody that answered...You all have the right answer btw.

Comment: You should set the derivative equal to zero, not the function itself.

Comment: @Romaion. Can you show us how to find the derivative of your function?

Comment: $f' = \frac{(2x)(x^2+x+2)-x^2(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+2)^2}+ \frac{2x^3+2x^2+4x-2x^3-x^2}{(x^2+x+2)^2}=\frac{x^2+4x}{(x^2+x+2)^2}$. Then $-4$ and $0$ are indeed critical points. Calculate the second derivative to determine if they are maxima or minima.

Comment: Or just make a number line of the first derivative and determine signs. After all, denom is always positive and never zero. Less algebra to go through

Answer (score 1):

[image: Using the quotient rule]

Note that the first derivative test is used to determine IF a point is a minimum or maximum point. (or neither) By setting the first derivative to 0, you are finding these critical points.

Tip: Sometimes, it helps to graph the function to get a general idea of what to expect in your answer.

Comment: Did you happen to use http://www.derivative-calculator.net/...

Comment: Yup! Why, is there a problem with the answer?

Comment: No, I just found it funny because I use it too, and I recognize the format

Comment: It really explains everything